# Returning custom HTTP status apache2

Tags: php, http, apache2

I'm hosting a webpage with apache and would like to be able to return custom HTTP status codes on a certain page. PHP does this just fine with `http_response_code($code)` but once it gets to apache it fails with HTTP 500. I have found where the http responses are defined in the apache source, but is it possible to modify this in configuration and without recompilation?

E.g. what's the easiest way to get custom HTTP statuses in apache2?